# Are the xor and not gates logically complete

Tags: logic, hardware, xor

Are the xor gate and the not gate logically complete. In other words, can we implement an logic circuit using them?

Comment: Since you can implement NOT with an XOR gate then the question reduces to: is the XOR gate logically complete ?

Comment: I don't see any way to implement OR or AND using XOR

Comment: I think with nor or nand you can create the others but I have not heard of xor or not being used.

Comment: @PaulR You **cannot** implement NOT with an XOR gate.

Comment: @AtulGangwar: sure you can - you set one input to 1 and then it becomes an inverter.

Comment: @PaulR You are checking for functional completeness. You have to implement every function with the operators in consideration and should work for every   input. So, if the input is all zeroes, you won't be able to implement the complement function.

In short, complement x if x is 0 using only XOR gate. You can't.

Comment: @AtulGangwar: 1 is just a constant - I don't see anything in the question that prevents an input from being connected to a constant 1 or 0. In the real world this would be equivalent to connecting an input to V+ or 0V. (Note that the OP specifically mentions a **logic circuit** and the question is tagged `hardware`.)

Comment: @PaulR
The tag is wrong and irrelevant. The question pertains to functional completeness.

In logic, a functionally complete set of logical connectives or Boolean operators is one which can be used to express all possible truth tables by combining members of the set into a Boolean expression.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness

And you cannot implement the truth table for NOT gate using only XOR gate in a boolean expression.
I will bet my life that I am correct :P

Comment: @AtulGangwar: you are presuming to read the mind of the OP - note that he nowhere refers to the formal concept of functional completeness. He specifically refers to a "logic circuit" and has tagged his question `hardware`. It appears therefore to be a practical question (SO is a site for practical questions, after all - there are other SE sites for theoretical problems). Unless you have personal knowledge of the OP and his requirements then it seems presumptuous and irrelevant to try and impose an arbitrary theoretical constraint on the question.

Comment: @PaulR well, you didn't mention the use of "1" in your old comment and I interpreted it the way I did - other computer science graduates should and probably would interpret it the same. So, when I read your comment I had to recheck it. No problem, the confusion is clear. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @AtulGangwar: glad the confusion is resolved - it's an interesting example of the gap between theory (CS in this case, presumably) and real world application (electronics, digital logic, chip design, programming, etc). In the real world `1` and `0` are readily available, and it's a common trick to use an XOR gate to implement an inverter like this. It's also useful for cases where you want to select "invert"/"don't invert" where one of the XOR inputs is the "signal" and the other input is the "control".

Answer (score 7):

NOR and NAND are the only functionally complete singleton gate sets. Hence, XOR is not functionally complete on its own (or together with NOT, since as point out above NOT can be created using XOR).

XOR can be complemented to a two-element functionally complete gate sets. One should add (left or right) implication.

You can find more about such sets in *Wernick, William (1942) "Complete Sets of Logical Functions," Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 51: 117–32.*

Comment: Umm.. NOT **cannot** be created using XOR

Comment: @AtulGangwar: of course it can - an XOR gate with one input set to 1 is an inverter.

Comment: @PaulR see my comment below the question.

Comment: See my further comment above.

Answer (score -2):

All of the basic logic gates may be created with the NOT gate. An XOR gate acts as a NOT gate if one of the inputs are permanently zero.

AND: NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(B))
OR: (may be made simply by connecting wires together, and maybe use some diodes)
NAND: NOT(A) OR NOT(B)
XOR: NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(B))) OR NOT(NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(B)) OR NOT(B))
ect.

Comment: Are you saying NOT gate alone is functionally complete? But the examples you gave need more than just NOT gate